# Find element containing unicode glyph with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup to find elements with specific unicode glyphs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols). I have an HTTML element that looks like:

```html
<li>&#9733; mytext</li>
```

I've tried:

```
# pattern = re.compile(r'&#9733)
pattern = re.compile(u'&#9733')
# pattern = re.compile('U+2605')
soup.find_all('li', text=pattern)
```

but in every case I get an empty list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unicode defines characters, not glyphs. And you should use the Unicode Standard as the reference, not Wikipedia pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a Unicode codepoint:

```
pattern = re.compile(u'\u2605')
```

See the [Python string literal documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import re
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<li>&#9733; mytext</li>')
>>> pattern = re.compile(u'\u2605')
>>> soup.find_all('li', text=pattern)
[<li>★ mytext</li>]
```

Comment: The point (no pun intended) is that you need to use the correct language-specific *escape notation* for a code point. All the codes in the question were attempts at providing a Unicode code point; they just fail because they are not the escape notations you should be looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I'm reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point, but is the code point here in u'\u2605' the "u" or the "\u" ?

Comment: @user61629: the codepoint is `2605`, but `\u` is the Python notation for specifying a Unicode character given a codepoint.

Comment: Understood, but I thought \u means "Character with 16-bit hex value xxxx (Unicode only)" (from your reference) ?

Comment: @user61629: yes, and the 16-bit hex value is a Unicode codepoint.